# pipe: Bad file descriptor

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a simpel c shell that will pipeline an arbitrary number of commands. Here is the relevant for loop:

```
int status;
int i,j,inputFile,outputFile,pid;
int pipeNum = info->pipeNum;

struct commandType *command;

int pipes[pipeNum * 2];
for(i=0;i<pipeNum;i++){
  pipe(pipes+2*i);
  printf("PIPE NUMBER %d CREATED\n", i+1);
}
for(j=0;j<=pipeNum;j++){
  if( ( pid=fork() ) ==0 ){
    if(j!=0){ 
      if(dup2(pipes[(j-1)*2],STDIN_FILENO)<0){
      perror("pipe");
      exit(2);
      }
    }
    if(j!=pipeNum){
      if(dup2(pipes[2*j+1],STDOUT_FILENO)<0){
      perror("pipe");
      exit(2);
      }
    }
    if(j==0 && info->boolInfile==1){
      if((inputFile = open(info->inFile,O_RDONLY))<0){
    perror("file");
    exit(2);
      }
      if(dup2(inputFile,STDIN_FILENO)<0){
      perror("dup2");
      exit(2);
      }
    }
    if(j==pipeNum && info->boolOutfile){
      if((outputFile = open(info->outFile,O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 666)<0)){
    perror("file");
    exit(2);
      }

      if(dup2(outputFile,STDOUT_FILENO)<0){
      perror("dup2");
      exit(2);
      }
    }
    for(i=0;i<pipeNum*2;i++){
      close(pipes[i]);
      }
    command=&info->CommArray[j];
    execvp(command->VarList[0],command->VarList);
    perror("Bad command");
  }
  for(i=0;i<pipeNum*2;i++){
    close(pipes[i]);
  }
  for(i=0;i<pipeNum+1;i++){
    wait(&status);
  }
}
```

But when I try to run the command

```
cat file.txt | wc
```

I get the following error:

```
pipe: Bad file descriptor.
```

Does anybody see the flaw in my code here? I can't figure it out to save my life.

I have added some print line statements and I get the bad file descriptor for every single pipe. ugh.

Comment: Using `perror("pipe");` after calls to `dup2()` is misleading.  For all practical purposes, you can't get EBADF from [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html), but you certainly can from [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html).  Please fix!

Comment: When you get to `j == pipeNum-1` in the last but one iteration of the loop, you are accessing elements of the `pipes` array that you never initialized (`if(dup2(pipes[2*j+1],STDOUT_FILENO)<0){` for example).

Comment: Yeah, but the perror("pipe") is really for my bennefit since it tells me where I'm screwing up...

Comment: That's my point: it doesn't tell you because you use the same (wrong) name each time.  OK; let's put it another way.  If I were going to use `perror()`, I'd be using `perror("dup2() - 1");` the first time, and `perror("dup2() - 2");` the second time, and so on, so I could see exactly which of the four `dup2()` calls is failing.  I tend not to use `perror()`; I prefer to have more control over the information passed.  But using `perror()` is several cuts above not testing, or using `printf()`, or various other misdeeds frequently seen here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The bad lines of code are at the very end of the for loop. Instead of

```
  }
  for(i=0;i<pipeNum*2;i++){
    close(pipes[i]);
  }
  for(i=0;i<pipeNum+1;i++){
    wait(&status);
  }
}
```

I should have

```
  }    
} 
for(i=0;i<pipeNum*2;i++){
    close(pipes[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<pipeNum+1;i++){
    wait(&status);
}
```

Comment: That is a problem. But how does that result in the observed symptoms where the `dup2` call fails?